# How to limit only certain users to access the work item?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using the custom process which inherited from the standard Agile process and is using Bug work item type to permit users to log the bugs. We create a new WIT: "Bugs in UAT". And there is a group of users - "UAT Testers". We can grant them either Stackholders or Basic Access Level licenses.

Would you be so kind to advise how is better to accomplish the following tasks:

1. UAT Testers group members should **only** be able to use "Bugs in UAT" WIT to log bugs. I.e. UAT Testers should have no access to anything except "Bugs in UAT".
2. Other users will need to use all WITs, including "Bugs in UAT".

Thank you very much for your help, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Work item permissions are not per-work item type, and there is no way to make them be. Permissions can be assigned at the area path level, and **anything** under that area path is visible to anyone who has access to it.

Honestly, having "Bugs" and "Bugs in UAT" seems like a big red flag to me. "UAT" should be a column on your backlog board, not a separate work item type. A bug is a bug.